# How can I convert a String array to a different Class ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to figure out how to write logic to convert an array of string into an ArrayList weekday object

```
String[] weekdays = request.getParameterValues("weekday");
```

I've made my ArrayList weekday2 the length of my String[] weekdays.

```
ArrayList<WeekDay> weekdays2 = new ArrayList<WeekDay>(weekdays.length);
```

I know there is a way to utilize enums, and that's what I'm trying to do.

```
for (int i = 0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
            weekdays2.add(new WeekDay().valueOf(weekdays2, weekdays));
        }
```

I know I'm definitely missing something.

error:

```
The method valueOf(Class<T>, String) in the type Enum<WeekDay> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<WeekDay>, String[])
```

Comment: How WeekDay looks like?

Comment: @alexander - It just has an enum in it. The array and arraylist above are in one of my servlets. My WeekDay enum is just this currently.

Comment: @alexander public enum WeekDay {
 
 MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY

}

Answer (score 1):

Code to get list of WeekDay may be such:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
        weekdays2.add(WeekDay.valueOf(weekdays[i]));
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest to add `toUpperCase()` since `valueOf()` matches for the exact identifier.

Comment: I think when you develop web application you control all possible parameter values.

Comment: Yeah you're right, however this would make the code a little safer at low cost.